# Proving by induction that every injection $f: A \to A$ is surjective if $A$ is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove by induction that if $A$ is a finite set, then an injection $f: A \to A$ is surjective. I've been able to prove that with the lemma that every injection admits a left inverse, but not with induction. The notation of induction on $|A|$ is also confusing to me, as the inductive hypothesis typically states "assumes the result is true when $|A| = k$," and then takes $A$ to be a $(k+1)$-element set. It sounds simpler to state it in terms of any $k$-element set. I'm also not sure if I need to establish the $k=1$ case, i.e, if it matters whether $k + 1 \geq 2$, but I believe so, since I reference two elements $x_1$ and $x_{n+1}$ in my argument. I'm hoping someone can check over the phrasing of my proof in particular.

> We prove by induction that for every $n \geq 0$, an injection from an $n$-element set is also a surjection. When $n = 0$, the only injection is the empty function, which is vacuously surjective. When $n = 1$, the only injection is the identity function, which is surjective, with the single element of the set serving as its own preimage. Suppose inductively that an injection from any $k$-element set is surjective, where $k \geq 1$. Now suppose that $|A| = k + 1$ and $f: A \to A$ is an injection. Write $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_k, a_{k+1}\}$. We either have $f(a_{k+1}) = a_{k+1}$ or $f(a_{k+1}) \neq f(a_{k+1})$. If $f(a_{k+1}) = a_{k+1}$, then define $A' := A - \{a_{k+1}\}$. Every element of $A'$ has an image in $A'$ since $f$ was injective, so $f^{*}: A' \to A'$ defined by $f^{*} (x) = f(x)$ is well-defined. As $f$ was injective, $f^{*}$ is also injective. Furthermore, $A'$ has $k$ elements, so by the induction hypothesis, $f^{*}$ is surjective. Therefore, $f$ is also surjective. For each of $a_1, \ldots, a_k$, there exists a preimage in $A'$, and $a_{k+1}$ is its own preimage. Suppose now that $f(a_{k+1}) \neq a_{k+1}$. Without loss of generality, and relabeling $a_1, \ldots a_k$ if necessary, we can assume $f(a_{k+1}) = a_1$. Define $g: A \to A$ by
> $$g(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> x_{n+1} & \text{ if $x = x_1$} \\ 
> x_1 & \text{ if $x = x_{n+1}$} \\ 
> x & \text{ otherwise.}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> By construction, $g$ is bijective. Therefore, $g \circ f$ is the composition of injections and hence injective. Furthermore, we have
> $$
> (g \circ f)(x_{n+1}) = g(f(x_{n+1})) = g(x_1) = x_{n+1},
> $$
> so $g \circ f$ is an injection from $A$ to $A$ which fixes $x_{n+1}$. We proved earlier that such a map is surjective, so it is bijective, hence $|(g \circ f)(A)| = |A|$. Furthermore, $|g(f(A))| = |f(A)|$. Composing maps, we get $|f(A)| = |A|$. As $f(A)$ is a subset of $A$ with the same size as $A$, we find that $f$ is surjective.

How does this look? there are a few jumps in the argument. I'm fairly sure that $|g(f(A))| = |f(A)|$, for example, but I don't know how to prove this. Do I regard $g$ as a function from $f(A)$ to $A$?

Comment: Assuming that when $A$ has 1 element, that the injection $f$ is surjective, an easier approach is to assume that when $A$ has $N$ elements, that the injection $f$, being a surjection must also have exactly $N$ distinct elements in its range.  Then, as the number of elements in $A$ increases by $1$, you have that $f$, being an injection must have the number of elements in its range also increase by $1$.  This forces $f$ to continue to be a surjection, when the number of elements in the domain of $A$ goes from $N$ to $N+1$.

Comment: **However,** it may be reasonably argued that my previous comment is not a **valid** use of induction, because my comment rests on the underlying assumption that if the set $A$ has a finite number of elements $M$, then any injection $f$, whose domain is $A$ must have exactly $M$ elements in its range.  This underlying assumption leads to a direct proof of the assertion, bypassing any use of induction.  So, it can be argued that my previous comment is not the approach intended by the problem composer.